# Is their a way to give optifine more antialiasing options

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-optifine, minecraft-shader

Recently I've been working on adding super secret setting back to minecraft and I found a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/c16gcm/enable_shaders_from_super_secret_settings_using/) that shows that you can make a resource pack and add the shader assets from 1.8 and renaming them to "fxaa_of_4x.json". But while messing around I realized I can switch between 2 shaders if i name one of them "fxaa_of_4x.json" and the other "fxaa_of_2x.json". But i got to wondering is their some code in the game i could change to let optifine have more antialiasing options so i could rename more shader files. Or is their or is their a way to easily skip dealing with adding more antialiasing options and just re add super secret setting completely. FYI i don'r really mind changing any code and i think i could google my way through it but i don't want to use a mod to do this for me. Also I'm not really sure if this post belong hear.

Comment: Wait, what's the point of antialiasing a 16x game?

Comment: Its not that I want antialiasing 16x in the game but if I can make the game give more options in antialiasing I can just rename all of the super secret settings shaders fxaa_of_8x.json, fxaa_of_16x.json and so on.